# API Call Requires 21 How to solve this error

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

how to solve the api call requires 21 error and please read this image and tell me how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: see, your calling method that is available from API level 21 onwards but your minimum API 19 therefore devices having API level 19 or 20 won't be able to use this method, do as suggested in the message or use alternate methods

Answer (score 0):

change your target Api version in Gradle (app) file to 21.

Comment: the @Yamini answer is good, but I think it's better to change your Target Api version. because it prevent the future problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Toolbar` to `SupportActionBar` to make it work for older api's as well.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.Profile));
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // For back button
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); // For back button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by changing the minSdkVersion of your project in the application level build.gradle file.

Navigate to your app's build.gradle file.
(TIP: Hold Ctrl+Shift+N to open File Search, then type "build", and click on **build.gradle (app)**)

Change the **minSdkVersion** to 21 as shown below:

```
android{

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
}
}
```

You can also use a value greater than 21 (currently the latest version is 27). But, make sure to also update the support library versions in the dependencies respectively.